# How to make SQL Server Database Mail use "PLAIN" authentication (instead of "LOGIN" authentication)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2019, database-mail

I'm having issues sending Database Mail with "PLAIN" authentication on two different versions MSSQL Server.

- SQL Server 2012
- SQL Server 2019

**Context**

I have created backup jobs which regularly backup some databases to files and report success or errors via email.

I have managed to configure `Database Mail` to send out the respective messages, and  confirmed via Wireshark and by studying the logs of the SMTP server that the emails are getting to the SMTP server.

**Problem**

However, I have a problem which is a show stopper. A user must log in into the SMTP server before the latter accepts the user's messages. `Database Mail` indeed tries to log in with the correct credentials, but uses `LOGIN` authentication, while the SMTP server only accepts `PLAIN` authentication.

That is, when establishing the communication, `Database Mail` at some point issues `AUTH LOGIN ...` when it should issue `AUTH PLAIN ...`. Subsequently, it sends the credentials in the wrong form. Therefore, it is currently impossible to let `Database Mail` send messages using the SMTP server in question.

How can I make `Database Mail` use `PLAIN` authentication?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for Basic authentication:

[image]

But if the Database mail was working and suddenly stopped there is the chance that [2FA has been enabled](https://www.jeeja.biz/2021/07/01/sql-server-why-your-database-mail-is-not-working-and-probably-never-will/).

You don't need Wireshark to check the SMTP server delivery success, you can check that on the Database Mail Log.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and +1. However, I already have used "Basic authentication" exactly as shown in your screenshot. The problem is that SQL server wants to use the "LOGIN" authentication method with the SMTP server instead of the "PLAIN" authentication method; this is shown by the SMTP server logs. The Database Mail logs are not very helpful, because they do not show the SMTP communication. Furthermore, I am 100% sure that 2FA is not the problem (it is not enabled at the SMTP server). The SMTP server log shows that the wrong authentication method is the problem.

Comment: @Binarus, SQL Server Database Mail offers `Windows Authentication`, `Basic Authentication` and `Anonymous Authentication`. I searched on Google for `sql server mail "plain" authentication` and I found nothing. I don't know what Plain Authentication means and I don't find documentation about that. Where did you fin the words `Plain Authentication` and what they stand for?

Comment: It's a matter of SMTP. Extremely oversimplified, when a piece of software talks to a SMTP server which requires authentication, there are generally different methods to authenticate, like `PLAIN`, `LOGIN`, `CRAM-MD5` and so on. Of course, only methods can be used which are supported by both parties. https://www.samlogic.net/articles/smtp-commands-reference-auth.htm may be a good starting point and roughly explains the three methods I mentioned, but there are more. I'm afraid that we can't configure SQL server in this respect (as we both couldn't find appropriate hints).

Comment: As for the options in the screenshot: I don't know exactly how `Windows Authentication` works, but it would be the wrong option for us, because the SMTP server is not running under Windows. `Anonymous authentication` is probably for SMTP servers which don't require authentication at all, which does not apply to our SMTP server. `Basic authentication` is the right thing, but leads to the problem described above. In other words, when choosing `Basic authentication`, there should be an additional dropdown list for the authentication method (`PLAIN`, `LOGIN` etc.).

Comment: @Binarus describe `PLAIN`, please. In What way is different from `LOGIN` which is user/password

Comment: It's explained in detail in the link I gave. It's a different protocol. One difference would be that the server answers with `334` after `AUTH PLAIN`, where it answers `334 VXNlcm5hbWU6` after `AUTH LOGIN`. Another difference is that a client may issue `AUTH PLAIN xxxx`, where xxxx is a base64-encoded string which contains user name and password together. This is not possible with `LOGIN`. And so on ... The explanation is quite good on the page I have linked, and by far too long to copy it here :-)

Comment: Can yo change the SMTP Server Authentication from `PLAIN` to `LOGIN`? Is that an option for you? Is the first time I face this issue. I'll try to see if I can reproduce this at home

Comment: @Binarus, there is the chance that the SMTP Server supports both PLAIN and LOGIN auth.  Check the PLAIN: https://www.ndchost.com/wiki/mail/test-smtp-auth-telnet. Check the LOGIN: https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/164907/test-smtp-authentication-with-messaging.html . I cannot believe you are the first human being facing this problem

Comment: Well, as I wrote in my question, that specific SMTP server only supports `PLAIN`, which is probably very rare. But I guess we are now at the point where it's better to use a different SMTP server, or to reconfigure that specific one to handle `LOGIN` as well. We would still prefer Database Mail using `PLAIN`, but since that doesn't seem to be possible, we'll go another route. Thanks for all your support and effort!